# When, How and Why soul take entry first time into cycle of birth and death?

Tags: karma, atma, death, rebirth, birth

It's usual to say that we take birth by birth into different species based on our [Karm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karma) and desires until one gets [Moksha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moksha). After Moksha one will not take any more births.

This makes us think When, Why and How [soul](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soul) make entry for the first time into this cycle of birth and death? So after entry into this cycle the soul is taking different birth based on Karma and Desires etc.

We talk about getting out from this cycle of birth and death, we call this as Moksha or Liberation.

But what about entry into this cycle? Why, How and When does this happen?

Comment: the wish of god only takes and removes us from this cycle, adn that only keeps us

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi: If everything is God's wish then I should re-write my question as...By God's wish Why, when and How soul take entry into cycle of birth and death? By God's wish many people talk about getting out of this cycle of brth and death so we have a concept of Moksha. By God's wish I want to know about entry into this cycle which people want to get out if it.

Comment: your question is too broad as the answer depends upon which school, the advaita, visistadvaita, or dvaita.